# MySQL GROUP BY with specific value and remaining as 'other'

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table "Staff" it has a column "staffNationality" with all the countries of staffs. I want a query to count the staffs and group the nationalities according to ONE country (for example: France) and count all other countries as "Other". Instead of showing the count for each country.

like this:

| staffCount | staffNationality |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | France |
| 10 | Other |

Comment: add the source data to your ask to provide more clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use conditional aggregation here:

```sql
SELECT
    CASE StaffNationality WHEN 'France'
                          THEN 'France' ELSE 'Other' END AS StaffNationality,
    COUNT(*) AS staffCount
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select count(1) as staffCount,case when nationalities = 'France' then 'France' else 'Other' end as staffNationality 
from Staff s
join staffNationality sn on s.staffid = sn.staffid
```